# my Div tags are breaking when I zoom in and zoom out my page in IE

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My Div is moving when I zoom in and zoom out.. Can anybody help me out?

```
<table style="position:fixed; top:70px; right:400px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="container body-content">
                @RenderBody()
                <footer>
                    <p>Confidential Information</p>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have two div tags in my main page.

```
<div>
 showing left side of the mian page
</div>

showing right side of the page.
<div style="position:absolute; right:-300px; top: 10px">
</div>
```

Working good for 75% zoom level but not in 100% and 50% zoom leavel.

Comment: Can you show your CSS? You labeled css on your question but your are not showing it. Your div classes might be causing it....

Comment: sorry I have updated my question.. Just I have two div tags I am not really using CSS here though just div tags.

Comment: I got what is the Issue. Instead of using right:400px I used Margin-right:300px. It resolved my Issue.